# Pass Multiple values to ActionMethodSelectorAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.Net 4.61, MVC5

I would like to catch Submit from 3 buttons in the same Action.

I am using `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` to catch which Submit button is pressed.  It's working fine for one Submit button.  But as shown in the following, if I want to catch 3 buttons in one action method, it doesn't work and I don't know how to pass the List to the attribute.

[image]

When Eng, Mat or ICT is clicked, I would like to display list of grades for the Clicked button.  The nature of these 3 buttons are almost the same.  They go to the database and extract the data due to the Subject

[image]

**FromValueRequiredAttribute.cs**

```
public class FromValueRequiredAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }
        public List<string> ButtonNameList { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(ButtonName) != null;
        }
    }
```

So, at the moment, I gave the same name to those 3 buttons like the following and check the button's Value to detect which button is clicked.

```
<button type="submit" name="ViewSubject" class="btn btn-success" value="ENG">English</button>
<button type="submit" name="ViewSubject" class="btn btn-info" value="MAT">Maths</button>
<button type="submit" name="ViewSubject" class="btn btn-warning" value="ICT">ICT</button>
```

Could you please suggest me know how I could pass the List to the Attribute?

**Updated1** : That's how I am doing at the moment.
[image]

Comment: Why do you want the list ? Use can click only one button at a time to submit the form. All you need is to know which button was clicked ?

Comment: I have updated my question.  I want to combine those 3 buttons because they are doing exactly the same.  All they did is call this method.  GradeService.GetExamGradesToUpdate(GradeName);  So, I don't want to create 3 actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When Eng, Mat or ICT is clicked, I would like to display list of
>   grades for the Clicked button. The nature of these 3 buttons are
>   almost the same.

You can simply use a parameter in your HttpPost action method with the same name as of your submit button's name.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string ViewSubject)
{
    var g = GradeService.GetExamGradesToUpdate(ViewSubject);
    // do something with g
    // to do : Return something
}
```

When one of those buttons (in the form) is clicked, the parameter ViewSubject will have the value(`value` attribute value) of the clicked button.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly, what I am doing now.  It's in my updated1 screenshot.  So, I assume that my idea about passing List to the attribute is crazy.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.  I managed to pass string array to the attribute.  Anyway, I still need to detect which button is clicked.  Our original solution is still better than my new crazy idea.